# Is it a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios

I want to know if this control derives  from UITableViewController?

[image]
If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you add the UISwitch view to the table cell. (As an accessory)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //add a switch
    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    [switchview release];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What about the other controllers in the accessoryView? Like  Preview  > 2 Lines

Comment: You better reference the Apple's Table View Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

Answer (score 1):

yes it is a table view Controller .. Grouped style ... first section has 7 rows 
I cannot say for sure if derived or not but i suppose not... you can addView to specific row so you can customize the cell ...deriving tableCell is not mandatory

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean.

If you mean how they have UISwitch in a table cell then its probably a subclass of UITableViewCell that they put a UISwitch in.

Comment: Or they've possibly just added a `UISwitch` as the cell's `accessoryView`, which wouldn't require a subclass. But either approach would work, and I'm basically splitting hairs.

Comment: Sorry for the red rectangle. I want to know about superview of the switch.